# Passing data from child component to parent component error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I am passing my data from the child component to parent component on the click of the button and generating the data as graph. But the data from the child component shows undefined as soon as it's state is updated hence no data gets pass to the parent component.

Here is my Parent Component:

```
class ButtonAll extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            childData: ''
        }
    }

    getData = (data) => {
        this.setState({
            childData: data
        })
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                <div>
                    <YearButton sendData={this.getData} />
                </div>
             </div>
           )
}
export default ButtonAll;
```

Here is my Child Component:

```
class YearButton extends Component{

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            data1: [],

        }
    }

    getData = async () => {
        var res = await axios.get('http://132.148.144.133:5000/api/v1/resources/tweet/count/xxhkfh2873jiqlp');
        var data1 = JSON.parse(res.data);
        data1 = data1.map(el => [el[0]*1000, el[1]]); 
        console.log(data1, 'first data');

        this.setState({
            data1: data1
        }, () => {
            this.props.sendData(this.state.data1)
        })
}

    render(){

        return(
            <div>
                <button className="year" onClick={this.getData}>year</button>            
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default YearButton;
```

As soon as I hit the button, it consoles `undefined` for the line `this.props.sendData(this.state.data1)`.

I have to achieve similar thing for other components too but nothing is getting passed to the parent. Please help the issue.

Comment: please upoad content in the data1 from response

Comment: @KishanJaiswal [[1556285400, 22], [1556285460, 17], [1556285520, 13], [1556285580, 13], [1556285640, 3]], this is the response from data1

Answer (score 1):

in your child component pass props inside `constructor` and `super` as a argument.

Comment: I passed it. Still the props of the parent component are empty.

Comment: @bubble-cord i have executed your code with my sample data in place of your API request and it is working fine.
i have created a stackblitz check it out : - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bq2wtu
open  console and see.

Comment: Can You please take a look at this. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bq2wtu. The code you edited executed properly. I rendered one more graph with its related data in the same code on the click of single button. But not working. Is it possible to pass multiple data streams, since I want to call multiple charts on single click?

Comment: @bubble-cord make sure to fork the project first on stackblitz then edit it and provide that URL.

Comment: I did some changes have a look https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xl4wtn

Comment: It's giving error when I am implementing the same code in my actual files. Working fine in online editor.  `Uncaught TypeError: _this.props.sendData is not a function at YearButton.<anonymous> (yearbutton.js:18)`

Comment: did you add _ (under score) before this?

Comment: No I didn't. This is the console printing the problem. I just followed your code into my actual local file.

Comment: have you tried calling props.sendData without using `this`

Comment: Worked. I deleted nodemodules folder and npm installed again. Thanks a lot for your help mate. :) You are a savior

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your constructor. if you use constructor you must provide props as param to constructor and super like below.

```
class YearButton extends Component{


    //the problem is here pass props as constructor param 
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data1: [],

        }
    }

   // or remove constructor write state like below 
   state = {
     data1 : [],
    }

    getData = async () => {
        var res = await axios.get('http://132.148.144.133:5000/api/v1/resources/tweet/count/xxhkfh2873jiqlp');
        var data1 = JSON.parse(res.data);
        data1 = data1.map(el => [el[0]*1000, el[1]]); 
        console.log(data1, 'first data');

        this.setState({
            data1: data1
        }, () => {
            this.props.sendData(this.state.data1)
        })
}

    render(){

        return(
            <div>
                <button className="year" onClick={this.getData}>year</button>            
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default YearButton;
```

Comment: I tried both your methods. Still the parent component not receiving any props. Without that, I am not able to pass those props from parent further to another component.

Answer (score 0):

You are not binding your **getData()** method in the constructor.

Your constructor function should look like this

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);

    this.state = {
        data1: [],

    }
}
```

Same is the case with your child component. Your function in the child component should bind this in the constructor.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Since I am already using fat-arrow function, I don't think it will be necessary to bind the getData() in the constructor. But if you can provide some reference.